# AJAX Reload Method?

Tags: javascript, ajax

I tried this to reload the page without refreshing [AJAX...], but doesnt seem to be working :/

```
function refresh() {
   link = document.location;
   xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
   xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
      if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200) {
         document.getElementsByTagName('table').innerHTML=xmlHttp.responseText;
      }
   }
   xmlhttp.open("GET",link,true);
   xmlhttp.send();
}
```

Anyone know what's wrong?

Comment: document.getElementsByTagName return an array of nodes, also you want to put the page into a table?

Comment: Im updating the contents of the table. So my method could be off.

Comment: Try `document.getElementsByTagName('table')[0]` or maybe you want to add an id to the table and do `document.getElementById('tableId')` Like @Musa said getElementsByTagName is basically an array

Comment: Besides, on IE, table innerHTML is read-only.

Comment: @dragon66 Indeed. @Alex Therefore, it is better to either wrap the table in a `<div>` and use its innerHTML to add the whole table (including the `<table>` tag). The other possibility is to access `<tbody>` instead of `<table>` which should work even in IE, if I recall correctly.

Comment: @Imp: <tbody> is still read only, even <tr> is. <td> would be a choice. But I would rather go for the whole table update, it won't cost much to repeat the header and it's much cleaner. Seems the OP is also trying to update the whole content of the table.

Comment: There are several problems here, so you may want to decide if you want to use ids on your elements, and update your code to do that, and, pass json back rather than html so each cell can be updated as needed, then show the new code and where you are at.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use innerHTML, it's a proprietary Microsoft Jscript method that doesn't properly register the DOM. In example if you use it to import an element with an ID it's less akin to putting a crown on a queen's head and more akin to dumping bodies by a bridge, the may or may not have seen it, likely not. Stick to using importantNode with AJAX and your AJAX loaded content will work reliably. Also code is not text, do not use responseText, use responseXML. Then instead of having to re-request the same content you can simply unhide the layer that is already in the DOM unless you expect the content to have been updated in the past X number of seconds in which case you can delete the element and redo the AJAX request. See my video for a visual demonstration...

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-iVebYrrz9U